# ASPX page markup validation element not supported

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am having an issue where elements in a `<%@ %>` tag on an aspx page are giving validation errors. For example, at the top of each aspx page there is a `<%@ Page %>` element and hovering over the Page text pops up the following validation message:

`Validation (HTML 4.01): Element 'page' is not supported.`

Other asp controls are not causing any validation errors such as asp:Content, asp:Button, and so on. It is only elements within the <%@ %> tag. Any idea what this could be? I tried other solutions I found here such as deleting the contents in the `ReflectedSchemas` folder, but that did not resolve my issue.

Comment: Is it possible that you copied and pasted the `page` directive from something with non-ascii characters in it?  I'd try just retyping it by hand just to make sure there are no special characters sneaking around in it that are messing with the parser.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I get the error on every aspx page, even newly created ones generated by VS. I have not pasted anything into the document.